# Meteor.userId() inside custom component not working properly on server, but it's fine locally.

Tags: angularjs, meteor, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor

I am using Meteor and Angular, and am having a hard time making my admin-specific code function properly. Locally, it works great, but once I use `meteor build` and put it up on the server, my code doesn't function, but I don't see any errors either. Specifically, inside my `/imports/components/storyAdmin.js` file, I have the following method:

```
this.isAdministrator =  Meteor.call('users.isAdmin', Meteor.userId(), function(error, result) {
    if (result) {
        _that.isAdministrator = result;
        _that.scope.$digest();
    }
});
```

The problem is, it doesn't seem to run, and I can't really debug on the server since the code is all minified and uglified (I think that's the word).

Am I going about this the wrong way? I Googled a lot about this and haven't found a good way to do it yet, or how to fix the issue I'm having.

Comment: When are you doing your Meteor.call ? Isn't this.isAdministrator always undefined ?

Comment: The Meteor.call is happening in the constructor of my StoryAdminController, so I'm guessing just on page load.

Comment: Could you try to place the meteor.call inside a tracker.autorun and also log the error when there is an error ?

Comment: How can I log the error? This is only happening once I put it up on my server (not locally) and I'm not getting an error on the server. I'm guessing I should just put the Tracker.autorun around my above code, and put it up on the server and see what happens, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You have a `error` variable in your callback. Just do `if(error)console.error(error);` Yes put the code in a tracker.autorun.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that and let you know what I see. I can't deploy it until this evening probably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162462/discussion-between-nicholaus-chipping-and-user3636214).

Comment: Side note (not sure if it's related to your issue or not), but you should not pass the `userId` to the server from the client. Use the server to check the Id. see [Meteor Security Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html)